# Using WCF service in MonoTouch with Authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.ios, wcf-security, wcf-client

I am using a WCF service client generated by slsvcutil form Silverlight toolkit version 4. I've also tried version 3 with the same problems. When I use a client instance running on http with no user credentials it runs without problems. But I need to switch to https for productive servers and send user credentials that are hardcoded for my application. I use the following code for that:

```
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding (BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);         
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress (AppSettings.FlareEndPoint);
        _service = new TopicAnalystAPIClient(binding, endpoint);
        _service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx";
        _service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password =  "xxx";
```

When I call a method on that service pointing to http with no authentication it works. When I use the this code against http/https with the credential I get "There was an error on processing web request: Status code 401(Unauthorized): Unauthorized" exception. I've checked that the credentials are correct, I am able to open the service reference in my browser. I've also tried several combinations of http/https and SecurityMode value. I've also tried it on four different servers always with the same result.

What can be the problem?

Comment: See my question which is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667030/make-this-wcf-client-code-work-on-mono-and-monotouch-on-the-mac

Answer (score 1):

A lot of permutations are possible. BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly should be usable without SSL [1] using HTTP itself. This means the server will send one (or more) authentication method(s) to the client (e.g. basic, digest, ntlm) and Mono (including MonoTouch) should be providing support for the most of them.

It is possible that the linker (if used) removes one of them. In that case you could try building and testing without linking (or skip linking of System.Net.dll).

It's also possible that the authentication method that the serve insist on is not supported. You could find which one is used by running a network trace (e.g. wireshark) or, maybe, it will show up in more details in the server log (along with the 401 error).

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpsecuritymode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx