# Make this WCF client code work on Mono and MonoTouch on the Mac?

Tags: wcf, mono, xamarin.ios

I am trying to get the following piece of code to work in a Mono console app and as the ultimate goal in a MonoTouch application. The code works fine under VS2008 using a Windows console app.
When running it as a Mono console app on the Mac, I get

> Unhandled Exception: System.NotImplementedException: The requested
>   feature is not implemented.   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement.CanBuildChannelFactory[IDuplexChannel]
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext context) [0x00000] in
>   :0

In MonoTouch, I receive this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error
>   occurred when verifying security for the message.   at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request
>   (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00188] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:545

Can somebody eplxain what is wrong? There is no app.config involved to keep things simple.

```
using System;
using MonoAPI3.BLAPI3Session;
using Brainloop.ServiceLibrary.DataModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel;

public static void Main()
{
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) => { return true; };

var oClient = new SessionServiceClient( new BasicHttpBinding( BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential )
            {
                CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 10 ),
                OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan( 0, 1, 0 ),
                ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan( 0, 1, 0 ),
                SendTimeout = new TimeSpan( 0, 1, 0 ),
                AllowCookies = false,
                BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
                HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
                MaxBufferSize = 65536,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536,
                MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text,
                TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
                UseDefaultWebProxy = true,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                {
                    MaxDepth = 32,
                    MaxStringContentLength = 8192,
                    MaxArrayLength = 16384,
                    MaxBytesPerRead = 4096,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384
                }

            },
            new EndpointAddress( "https://service.myserver.com/Service/V3/Session.svc" ) );

            oClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user@domain.com";
            oClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";

            SessionInfo oInfo = oClient.StartSession();

            Console.WriteLine( "SESSION HASH: " + oInfo.SessionHash );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem line of code is:

```
BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential
```

Mono does not support WS-Security.  Basically there are many options on BasicHttpSecurityMode which will not work.  If you require Message Credentials, then I'm afraid this code cannot be made to work.  Here is a related link:

http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2010-January/096972.html

Comment: The link you refer to talks about MonoTouch. That's an issue bt what about plain Mono console app under Mac OS? See my post above, it doesn't work in Mono either. So is the problem in MT or in Mono?

Comment: It seems to be an issue in MonoTouch because the same code works on console app unde MacOs using mono but it doesn't work on iPad app using the same code but built using MonoTouch.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to download the attachment from [this link](https://bugzilla.novell.com/attachment.cgi?id=363641&action=edit).

I was successful with getting it to work. I set the Web project on Windows machine under **IIS 7** with only **basic authentication** enabled and **.NET authorization** to a **specific user**.
Then I just run the console app under MonoDevelop on my Mac machine and it worked without any errors.

The only difference I can see between the Mono console app and MonoTouch app is this line:

```
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
```

In the MonoTouch app the binding.Security.Transport property is not generated.

Comment: I will try that after talking to our WCF specialist providing the services